# Set default Value of List Lookup Column based on Site Name

Tags: aggregation

I've built a series of Project Sub-sites, each with a Task list that includes the Project Name.  The sub-site name is also the project name.  How can I set the default value of the Project Lookup column using this sub-site name?  I'm doing this to be able to roll-up all the tasks by project to the parent site using the CQWP.

Bismarck